# Put Time without Date in a Cell Jxl

Tags: time, jxl

I want to put the time on a cell. Here is the code I have so far:

```
DateFormat valueFormatDate = new DateFormat("HH:mm");
valueFormatDate.getDateFormat().setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
WritableCellFormat formatDate = new WritableCellFormat(valueFormatDate);
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
DateTime dt=new DateTime( 1, j+1,( java.util.Date )(formatter.parse(table.getValueAt(j, 1).toString())) ,formatDate);        s.addCell(dt);
```

My Problem is, that the date is displayed too. How can I only display the time?

Comment: And the question/issue is ?

Comment: sorry, am new here, my question is how can i put just time on a cell ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, worked for me.

SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss",new Locale("fr","FR"));
sheet.addCell(new Label(1,1, "Time: " + fmt.format(new Date())));